# How to create WCF config file automatically?

Tags: wcf, configuration

I have created a WCF service interface and implementation in a Class Library.

I haven't yet decided if the service will be self-hosted or hosted by a Windows Service.

How do I now create a console app (seperate project in Visual Studio) that will host my WCF service ? I know I can host it by programatically typing in all the configuration (like [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx)) but I don't want that.

I want this console app to have a configuration file that has the 'serviceModel' section in it already, so that all I will have to do in the Main function of the console app would be something like:

```
MyService service = new MyService();
service.Open();
```

And so 'Open' will read the configuration from the 'App.config' file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to manually add the section to the console application's configuration file. There is no "automatic" way to have the section added to an existing app.config.

Once that config section is in the console app's `app.config`, then your class library's WCF services will read it correctly, just like you want it to.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a self hosting template:

http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2010/10/wcf-self-hosting-also-in-vs-2010.html